# PHP: strftime(), date() or DateTime, Which is better?

Tags: php, date, strftime

I am curious to know if there is any advantage in PHP of using `strftime()` over `date()` or vice versa.

A class I downloaded used the `strftime()`. However, since it does not support all time formats on some systems, I want to change it to use `date()` instead. I was wondering if there are any major differances or advantages in using one over the other.

What about the fact that `strftime()` only supports date formats that are supported by that servers c library? Does `date()` have any similar restrictions?

Comment: There is yet another option, [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: very small performance difference... tiny

Comment: @Pekka To simply just find out the time or date, why would you use `DateTime` over `date()` or `strftime()`?

Comment: @Ibrahim Diallo  So, technically speaking, which is faster?

Comment: @Pekka, @Chaim DateTime wraps the functionality of other functions (strtotime(), date(), date_diff(), etc). In lots of cases the OO DateTime code is cleaner than using the "old" functions.

Comment: @James no, `DateTime` is not just a wrapper - it uses 64-bit dates internally, and thus can handle any kind of date (and not only 1902/1970 to 2038) @Chaim *faster*? That won't make any real-world difference except if you are planning to calculate thousands or hundreds of thousands of dates per request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you'll find `date()` is more widely used than `strftime()`

`date()` is only able to return month/day names in English and won't be able to give you translations for other languages.

The performance implications should be negligible.

If you decide to go the date route I'd really recommend using `DateTime` which makes most date and time related operations easier than using the original procedural functions.

Answer (score 13):

> is any advantage in PHP of using
>   strftime() over date()

From the [date manual page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> To format dates in other languages,
>   you should use the [setlocale](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)()
>   and [strftime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)() functions instead
>   of date().

Comment: So that means if I'm only using English anyway then date() is good enough, or better perhaps?

Comment: But this can be about some time, and you will need i18n in your application. With strftime() way you are ready for it.