# How to format short german day names with TYPO3 fluid viewhelpers and strftime?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, strftime

`strftime` returns only three letter weekday abbreviations, like "Thu". In german, that doesn't make any sense, it's Mo,Di,Mi,Do,Fr,Sa,So, not "Fre"...

How do I set

```
<f:format.date format="%A, %d.%m.%Y">{item.date}</f:format.date>
```

So that it appears correctly with the german locale?

Answer (score 1):

Just split it up and crop it separately...

```
 <f:format.crop append="" maxCharacters="2"><f:format.date format="%A">{item.date}</f:format.date></f:format.crop> <f:format.date format="%d.%m.%Y">{item.date}</f:format.date>
```

Comment: SO enforces a waiting period of 2 days for that

Answer (score 0):

Use only `D` in format. it's display only three letters. Like below

```
<f:format.date format="D">{item.date}</f:format.date>
```

Comment: The question is for 2 letters. Also, `date` doesn't return translations for weekday/month names, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941268/160968